# Hive: Create table with many incremental files

Tags: hive, hdfs

Is there a way to create a hive table with multiple incrementally named files? I've got a bunch of files separated by day and I'd like to create a table from a time range of those dates.

For example, if I wanted to just create a table from all files dated the month of August, how would I create that table? Would I have to individually add each file by altering the table or is their a regex like way of adding all files in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

The Hive metastore only tracks partition information and the path information for a given table. So to load data you don't necessarily have to be restricted to what the Hive LOAD DATA command can do.

Suppose you have an unpartitioned table called mytable in a db called mydatabase, and your hive warehouse directory is hdfs://apps/hive/warehouse. Then you can just move data into that directory and it will appear in the table (assuming the input format is compatible with what the table was created with). So you can just use your standard file system operations to move data, including using globs, e.g., to copy just the data for files starting with 2013-08, you may do something like:

```
hadoop fs -cp /my/hdfs/data/directory/2013-08-*.txt /apps/hive/warehouse/mydatabase.db/mytable
```

or if your data is on the local filesystem

```
hadoop fs -put /my/local/data/directory/2013-08-*.txt /apps/hive/warehouse/mydatabase.db/mytable
```